# Why is maximising expected monetary value not plausible for large amounts of money?

Tags: probability, economics, gambling, utility

My teacher asked us which of these gambles do you prefer:

$g_1=£500,000$

$g_2=0.1£2,500,000 \oplus 0.89£500,000 \oplus 0.01£0$

The EMV for each gamble is £500,000  and £695,000  respectively, indicating to me that $g_2$ is better. However my teacher said that for large amount of money, expected monetary value is not a plausible utility. Why is this?

Comment: Imagine you are dealing with free pizzas in a restaurant instead of 500,000 pounds. Getting one free pizza is probably a better deal than an 89% chance of one, 10% chance of five and 1% chance of none because you really don't need five pizzas. Marginal utility typically decreases as you have more of a certain item - even money. Also this isn't a math problem.

Comment: true.. for realistic purposes I guess people would rather a large amount with certainty than an extremely large amount with a small probability. So in this case the mathematical approach isn't practical